# Do I need a visa if traveling with my husband?

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, qatar

I am planning to visit my family in Qatar with my husband. He has a visa-free entry because he is German. I am wondering if I am traveling with him, does that mean that I can get visa-free entry as well?

I couldn't get any info about that one the internet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What passport do you have?

Comment: What passport do you have?

Comment: Moroccan passport, after I asked them they said i need an ETA  visa its online process thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You *may* need a visa. A visa is attributed to a single person and rules about requiring a visa or not are also attributed to a single person.

Whether your husband needs a visa or does not is irrelevant to your entry requirements. During the isa application process though, it sometimes can help but that is at the discretion of the one reviewing your application.

Comment: Some countries e.g. Oman grant an on-arrival visa to the accompanying spouses of certain nationalities as well. (The spouse coming alone wouldn't get the on-arrival visa)

Comment: @Newton - Never encountered that but I'm sure there are more rules than we can ever imagine!

Comment: Yes, apparently Qatar doesn't seem to have any such rule. Not mentioned anywhere so the OP will have to apply for an individual visa prior to travel.